# Need help vertically center a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I was wondering what would be the best way to vertically center a div inside another div. The only constraint I have is that .anim needs to remain relative!  I lsited the current code I have now down below. Thanks guys!

HTML:

```
<div class="anim">

         <div class="spacer">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <p>more content</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.anim {
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    height:50%;
}

.spacer{
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.anim{display:table;}
.spacer {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

would have it vertically aligned

Comment: You should use another block element between `.anim` and `.spacer` and set it to `display:table-row` if you are going to do something like this. CSS tables should mimic actual tables.

Comment: yea i tried that method earlier and oddly didn't work :/

Comment: not sure if you had the positioning stuff there earlier, but that would definately stop it from working

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to give your `.anim` div a fixed height of, let's say, 500px.

Then you can just add a `margin-top` :

```
.anim {
  margin-top: 100px;    // (500 - 300) / 2 = 100
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvu29/)

Comment: is there a way to do this without a fixed height? I'm using percentages :/

Comment: @kduan Having a fixed height element inside a variable-height container can be a problem: for instance, if 50% is equivalent to 200px, then your 300px element will overflow out of its parent element ! What is the logic behind this 50% height requirement ?

Comment: Well I have the screen divided in half. And I want to fit this div inside the bottom half.

Comment: For overflow I was planning on doing something different for mobile and smaller screens

Answer (score 0):

according to w3:  http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical

CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3. But even in CSS2 you can center blocks vertically, by combining a few properties. The trick is to specify that the outer block is to be formatted as a table cell, because the contents of a table cell can be centered vertically.

so the code is really simple

```
.anim {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
}
```

here is the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/AbTxS/

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the problem is that I can't have a fixed height :/. I should of mentioned that earlier Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you want something like this... `div.spacer` is vertically centered and `div.anim` remains relative.

The `div.spacer` top margin must be negative half of the `.spacer` height.

This solution only works with a fixed height for `.spacer`.

CSS

```
.anim {
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    height:800px;
    background:#FF0
}    
.spacer {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin:-150px 0 0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="anim spacer">
    <p>
        Content
    </p>
    <p>
        More content
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do fixed height sorry :/